# ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT ajax function not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When Adblock is active in chrome below script is not working in chrome. It shows error in console like this

> jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4 GET http://example.com/advertisement/mult_select/30 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>
> jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4 POST http://example.com/advertisement/getCategoryFieldsList/30/0 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

I have tried also anti-adblock-killer.user.js. But still it is not working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(event){
    
$('.category_1').live('change',function(){

var foo = []; 
var name = [];
$('.category_1 :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
  foo[i] = $(selected).val(); 
  name[i] = $(selected).attr("myTag");
});

//$('.category_title_0').html(name[0]);
var str = (foo[0]).replace(/\,/g, '');
$(this).parent('div').nextUntil('#tit').remove();
var str2 = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('parent_id');
$.ajax({
url: "<?= site_url('advertisement/mult_select')?>"+'/'+str,
success:function(result)
{
$('.mul-select').append(result);
}
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'script',
    url: "<?= site_url('advertisement/getCategoryFieldsList') ?>"+"/"+str+"/"+str2,
    success: function(result)
    {
        if($("#"+str2).length > 0)
        {
            $("#"+str2).empty();
            $("#"+str2).nextAll('*').empty();
            $("#"+str2).html( result );
        }
        else
        {
        $('#dynamic_fields_div').append( "<div id="+str2+"></div>" );
        $("#"+str2).html( result );
        }
    } 
});

});

});
```

Comment: i think adblock sees that the url contains the word "advertisement" and it thinks it's an ad. is it possible for you to change the url?

Comment: It is not possible. Because most of functions using this word. But i'm using anti-adblock-killer.user.js. any other way to resolve this ?

Comment: Create a rule in adblock plus to allow that domain and it works. If you need it for your clients, assume that clients that use adblock is often that some things in page doesn't work if don't disable adblock. You can detect adblock and if it's installed show an alert to client to say "to see the page working perfectly disable your adblock"

Comment: if you are talking about this: https://github.com/reek/anti-adblock-killer i don't think it does what you think it does. As far as i've understood This is a script you need to put inside your browser (not on websites) that will keep adblock active to sites that ask you to disable it

Comment: You don't need to change the functions, neither those inside your client code or those inside your server code, just the URL (that is, the string "advertisement/" ). I had a similar issue with kaspersky, on a site where the url had the words "toss" and "ban" (which kaspersky thought it was about banners, but it was actually needed to ban users)

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for your replies. solved issue as you told. Thanks alot :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please remember to accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is that adblock recognizes the word `advertisement` in the URL and it thinks it's an ad.
Many applications work this way (for example it happened to me that Kaspersky blocked a page on a site i own because it contained the words `toss` and `ban`) so you should be careful about the URL you write to take into account that visitors might have applications that block certain bad words.

Comment: Underrated answer... be careful of `ad` as well. Ran into an issue where my url contained `ad`, and it was getting blocked for some unknown reason. spent too long looking before I found this. 

Disable ad block and try again.

Comment: Here too underrated answer check that your microservices does not age ad in their url ...

Answer (score 2):

In my case i didn't have the name "advertisement" on the url path, but still got the same **ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT** error.

I resolved it by giving **cache: false** option to the $.ajax() function.

I am leaving this comment here, as it may be useful to someone.